# Monaco ttf font in Sublime text 3 for Ubuntu gives illegible rectangles

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, sublimetext3

I have installed Monaco from this [repository](https://github.com/todylu/monaco.ttf) by copying `monaco.ttf` to `.fonts` folder in my home of Ubuntu 15.04. After setting the font_face in user preferences of sublime, the font becomes illegible rectangles.

My `User/Preferences.sublime-settings` is as follows:

```
{
    "font_face": "monaco",
    "font_size": 9,
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Spacegray/base16-eighties.dark.tmTheme",
    "theme": "Spacegray Eighties.sublime-theme"
}
```

I have also tried using Monaco from [lowing.org](http://www.lowing.org/fonts/) and it gives the same result. I have seen articles on this font being used in Mac and Windows. Is there a way I can use this font in Sublime 3 in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried "font_face": "Monaco" (with uppercase M)?

Comment: I have tried with uppercase M. It gives the same output.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem in my sublime text 3 build 3083 on Linux Mint.

Comment: Have you installed the font by double clicking on the '.ttf' file?

Comment: Thanks @sergioFC and @Quark, I first tried to install the monaco.ttf which is in `.fonts` folder. It failed because the font was already in `~/.local/share/fonts`, which might have got there due to my previous corrupt installation. I removed `~/.local/share/fonts/monaco.ttf` and installed again. It worked this time.

Comment: Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't figure out why my previous installation failed, giving those rectangles. Although I am able to get it working by re-installing.

I first deleted the previously installed monaco.ttf located in `~/.local/share/fonts`. I then downloaded a fresh copy of monaco.ttf, copied it to `~/.fonts` folder and installed it through font viewer that comes packed with Ubuntu and can be accessed by double-clicking the font in file manager.

On adding `"font_face": "monaco"` to sublime user preferences, the font is now properly rendered.